# strtolower behaves differently in cli and fpm modes?

Tags: php, string

I use windows, php version is 5.6.38, try to use strtolower for a Chinese character, but the output in cli mode and fpm mode is different. Why is that? Below is my code.

```
<?php
$str = "星";
echo ord($str[0]) . ',' . ord($str[1]) . ',' . ord($str[2]) . "----" ;
$str = strtolower($str);
echo ord($str[0]) . ',' . ord($str[1]) . ',' . ord($str[2]) ;
?>
```

The above example in cli will output:
230,152,159----230,152,255

The above example in fpm will output:
230,152,159----230,152,159

Answer (score 0):

The two environments are likely running under different locales. CLI will be picking up whatever configuration is set by your machine and php install; FPM will be picking up configuration set by the webserver as well.

You can check your locale by running:

```
echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);
```

As part of your script. I suspect you'll find `LC_CTYPE` to be different. You can also use `setlocale` to change your locale in your code, although you'd probably be better doing this through configuration.